# Random forest every run confusion matrix accuracy results change in R. How to make sure what is accuracy on test data

Tags: r, random-forest

```
cv.folds <- createMultiFolds(train$Label,k = 10, times = 3)
cv.cntrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10,
                         repeats = 3,index = cv.folds,search="grid")

Model_RF_RF<-randomForest(Label ~ .,data = train.tokens.tfidf.df,ntree=500,mtry=82,importance=TRUE,
                          proximity=TRUE,trControl = cv.cntrl,nodesize=10)
```

Thiis is code for training the model and then apply to test data

```
t1<-tuneRF(train.tokens.tfidf.df[,-1],train.tokens.tfidf.df[,1],stepFactor = 0.5,plot = TRUE,
           ntreeTry = 500, trace = TRUE,improve =0.05)

# Total time of execution on workstation was
total.time <- Sys.time() - start.time
total.time
PD5<-predict(Model_RF_RF,train.tokens.tfidf.df)
confusionMatrix(PD5,train$Label )
comparison5<-cbind.data.frame(train$Label,PD5)
comparison5
```